# How to fully render custom element in aurelia component for e2e test?

Tags: aurelia

I am trying to write a test for an Aurelia component that uses the aurelia-bootstrap-datetimepicker from Aurelia-Bootstrap-Plugins. I am trying to figure out how to trigger an input event on then abp-datetime-picker element but am having problems due to the element not being fully rendered out. Here is how I am currently setting up the component being tested:

```
const bindingContext = {
   model: {...}
};

const component = StageComponent
  .withResources([
    `${componentPath}`,
    'resources/elements/custom-input-field/custom-input-field',
    'resources/elements/custom-radio-field/custom-radio-field'
  ])
  .inView(`<compose view-model="${componentPath}" model.bind="model"></compose>`)
  .boundTo(bindingContext);

component.bootstrap(aurelia => {
  aurelia.use
    .standardConfiguration()
    .plugin('aurelia-validation');
```

How can I set the value of the abp-datetime-picker component if it is not fully rendered on the document being tested?

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

The issue was in my karma.config.js, which was not serving node_modules html files. The fix was adding `{pattern: 'node_modules/**/*.html', included: false}` to the karma's `config.files`.